# What is the best way to debug Terraform AWS Application Load Balancer validation error?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to provision a demo web service on AWS with Terraform, and am encountering the following error.

```
Error: Error applying plan:

2 error(s) occurred:

* module.prod.module.web.module.web.aws_alb_listener.frontend: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_alb_listener.frontend: Error creating LB Listener: ValidationError: 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:114416042199:loadbalancer/app/demo-svc-prod-alb/2a5f486a7b9d265a' is not a valid target group ARN
  status code: 400, request id: e3819755-799c-11e8-ac82-43dfdd4e44d1
* module.prod.module.web.module.web.aws_autoscaling_group.backend: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_autoscaling_group.backend: Error creating AutoScaling Group: ValidationError: Provided Load Balancers may not be valid. Please ensure they exist and try again.
  status code: 400, request id: e37efee9-799c-11e8-955a-c50a9e447dfa
```

What I don't understand is why the ARN is invalid, as it belongs to a resource created by Terraform.  It seems perhaps suspicious that the ARN refers to `elasticloadbalancing`. Are there any gotchas to be aware of when working with an AWS application load balancer and an ASG?  When using a classic ELB I didn't see this problem.  Is there any way to get more useful information out of Terraform?

The relevant resources that throw the errors are:

```
resource "aws_alb_listener" "frontend" {
  load_balancer_arn       = "${aws_alb.frontend.arn}"
  port                    = "${local.https_port}"
  protocol                = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy              = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn      = "${aws_alb.frontend.arn}"
    type                  = "forward"
  }
}
```

and

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "backend" {
  name                    = "${local.cluster_name}-asg"
  launch_configuration    = "${aws_launch_configuration.backend.id}"
  availability_zones      = ["${data.aws_availability_zones.all.names}"]
  load_balancers          = ["${aws_alb.frontend.name}"]
  health_check_type       = "ELB"
  min_size                = "${var.min_size}"
  max_size                = "${var.max_size}"
  // This resource type uses different tags specification format.
  // A list comp over the locals tags map would sure come in handy to keep
  // things DRY.
  tags                    = [
    {
      key                 = "System"
      value               = "${var.tags["System"]}"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key                 = "Environment"
      value               = "${local.tags["Environment"]}"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key                 = "Owner"
      value               = "${local.tags["Owner"]}"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key                 = "Description"
      value               = "${local.tags["Description"]}"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
  ]
}
```

The full code is available at https://github.com/mojochao/terraform-aws-web-stack/commit/a4bfe5d6362fddfb2934dc9a89344c304e59cef7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to the wrong resources in both cases.

With the first error your listener is defined as:

```
resource "aws_alb_listener" "frontend" {
  load_balancer_arn       = "${aws_alb.frontend.arn}"
  port                    = "${local.https_port}"
  protocol                = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy              = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn      = "${aws_alb.frontend.arn}"
    type                  = "forward"
  }
}
```

Note that the [`default_action` takes a `target_group_arn`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb_listener.html#target_group_arn) so you need to point it to your target group, not the load balancer itself.

So instead you should use:

```
resource "aws_alb_listener" "frontend" {
  load_balancer_arn       = "${aws_alb.frontend.arn}"
  port                    = "${local.https_port}"
  protocol                = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy              = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn      = "${aws_alb_target_group.frontend.arn}"
    type                  = "forward"
  }
}
```

Because you only have a single listener rule defined you can also remove the [`aws_alb_listener_rule` resource](https://github.com/mojochao/terraform-aws-web-stack/blob/a4bfe5d6362fddfb2934dc9a89344c304e59cef7/modules/web/main.tf#L124-L137) because it's doing the same thing as the default action on the listener anyway. You would only define rules separately if you wanted different traffic (either by host or by path) to go to different target groups.

Your second error comes from trying to attach the autoscaling group to an ELB classic by [using the `load_balancers` parameter](https://github.com/mojochao/terraform-aws-web-stack/blob/a4bfe5d6362fddfb2934dc9a89344c304e59cef7/modules/web/main.tf#L40). As the [`aws_autoscaling_group` resource docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#load_balancers) mention you should use [`target_group_arns`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#target_group_arns) instead:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "backend" {
  name                    = "${local.cluster_name}-asg"
  launch_configuration    = "${aws_launch_configuration.backend.id}"
  availability_zones      = ["${data.aws_availability_zones.all.names}"]
  target_group_arns       = ["${aws_alb_target_group.frontend.arn}"]
  health_check_type       = "ELB"
  min_size                = "${var.min_size}"
  max_size                = "${var.max_size}"
  // This resource type uses different tags specification format.
  // A list comp over the locals tags map would sure come in handy to keep
  // things DRY.
  tags                    = [
    {
      key                 = "System"
      value               = "${var.tags["System"]}"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key                 = "Environment"
      value               = "${local.tags["Environment"]}"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key                 = "Owner"
      value               = "${local.tags["Owner"]}"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key                 = "Description"
      value               = "${local.tags["Description"]}"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
  ]
}
```

This will automatically attach the autoscaling group to the ALB target group so you can also get rid of the [`aws_autoscaling_attachment` resource](https://github.com/mojochao/terraform-aws-web-stack/blob/a4bfe5d6362fddfb2934dc9a89344c304e59cef7/modules/web/main.tf#L157-L160) which is doing the same thing. You would only normally use the `aws_autoscaling_attachment` resource if you defined your ALB target group and your autoscaling group separately and needed to link across them.

Comment: Thanks!  That solved it.  I also had to change this, as I was using `name` instead of `arn`.

`target_group_arns = ["${aws_alb_target_group.frontend.arn}"]`

Comment: Oh Man big Thanks @ydaetskcoR, you save my weekend ;)