# How to attach Two target group against single ECS services

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I am looking for a way to attach two target group against single ECS services, in other my container exposes two port but I am only able to map one port against my service to LB.

So far I am able to create a new listener and target group but after target group creation I can see everything as per expectation but the target group show `There are no targets registered to this target group`

[image]
Here are my target group and listener configuration

**target_group:**

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "e_admin" {
  name = "${var.env_prefix_name}-admin"
  port = 5280
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.VPC.id}"

  health_check {
    path = "/admin"
    healthy_threshold = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 10
    port = 5280
    timeout = 90
    interval = 100
    matcher = "401,200"
  }
}
```

**Listener:**'

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "admin" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_lb.admin_lb.arn}"
  port = "5280"
  protocol = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.e_admin.id}"
    type = "forward"
  }
}
```

My question is how I can add ECS cluster Autoscaling group or how I can add all the instances running in the ECS cluster to this target group?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AWS [recently announced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/register-multiple-targetgroups.html) support for multiple target groups for an ECS service.

The, currently unreleased, [2.22.0 version of the AWS provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2220-unreleased) contains support for this by adding more `load_balancer` blocks to the `aws_ecs_service` resource. Example from [the acceptance tests](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/421098b56f5c86942b64a047855d2124f0550fb1/aws/resource_aws_ecs_service_test.go#L2394-L2411):

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "with_alb" {
  name            = "example"
  cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.main.id}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.with_lb_changes.arn}"
  desired_count   = 1
  iam_role        = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_service.name}"

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.test.id}"
    container_name   = "ghost"
    container_port   = "2368"
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.static.id}"
    container_name   = "ghost"
    container_port   = "4501"
  }

  depends_on = [
    "aws_iam_role_policy.ecs_service",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Accodring to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html,

> There is a limit of one load balancer or target group per service.

---

If you want to attach a autoscaling group to the target group, use `aws_autoscaling_attachment`,
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_attachment.html

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "asg_attachment_bar" {
  autoscaling_group_name = "${aws_autoscaling_group.your_asg.id}"
  alb_target_group_arn   = "${aws_alb_target_group.e_admin.arn}"
}
```

Comment: But what about other way that attach auto scaling group

Comment: use `aws_autoscaling_attachment`, https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_attachment.html

Comment: I used it for auto scaling group for EKS, connected multiple ports to nlb target groups.  Did you create two target groups for each ports?

Comment: yes as you can see i mentioned, this for the second one

Comment: can you share your configuration please

Comment: `ValidationError: Provided Target Groups may not be valid. Please ensure they exist and try again.`

Comment: this worked for me @Ryankim https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052902/what-is-the-best-way-to-debug-terraform-aws-application-load-balancer-validation

Comment: you can update your asnwer, one point is valid that there is limit in your answer, so i add ` target_group_arns       = ["${aws_alb_target_group.frontend.arn}"]` in autoscaling group, if you want to update your answer you, this your point that lead to me to the actual solution. Thanks

Comment: This answer is no longer valid. According to AWS documentation, an ECS service can have up to 5 load balancers attached to it. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/register-multiple-targetgroups.html

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple define multiple target groups for the same ecs service using the `load_balancer` block.

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs_service_1" {
  name            = "service-1"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster_prod.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs_task_definition_1.arn
  desired_count   = 1
  launch_type = "FARGATE"
  enable_execute_command = true

# Target group 1
  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.lb_tg_1.arn
    container_name   = "app"
    container_port   = 8080
  }

# Target group 2
  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.lb_tg_2.arn
    container_name   = "app"
    container_port   = 8080
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets          = [aws_subnet.subnet_a.id, aws_subnet.subnet_b.id]
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.sg_internal.id]
    assign_public_ip = true
  }

  tags = {
    Name         = "service-1"
    ManagedBy    = "terraform"
    Environment  = "prod"
  }
}
```

You can map the same container and port to both target groups in case of having an external and an internal load balancer for example